# Matrix Multiplication using different classes - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, multiplication

I have this assignment for my class where I have to create a Matrix Multiplication program. Here's the condition:

Implement two types of algorithms for multiplying two n × n matrices. Assume n is a power of 2:

1. The straight-forward O(n^3) matrix multiplication algorithm.
2. Strassen’s matrix multiplication algorithm.

Evaluate your different algorithms, and write a short report. Create test matrices for different values of n (4, 10, 20,100). Generate matrices using random numbers. Compute the running time of your algorithms. Your report should include the running times and conclusions.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
public class MatrixMultiplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int rows = rand.nextInt(7) + 2;
       int columns = rand.nextInt(7) + 2;

       System.out.println("The matrix has " + rows + " randomized rows");
       System.out.println("The matrix has " + columns + " randomized column");

       System.out.println();

       double[][] a = new double[rows][columns];
       double[][] b = new double[columns][rows];

       System.out.println("The first matrix has the values: ");
       Matrix m1 = new Matrix(a);

       System.out.println("---------------------------------");
       System.out.println("The second matrix has the values: ");
       Matrix m2 = new Matrix(b);

       System.out.println();

       Matrix productRegular = m1.multiply(m2);

    }
}
```

**And here's my other class:**

```
import java.util.Random;

class Matrix 
{ 
    double[][] arrayA;
    double[][] arrayB;

    private Matrix(double[][] a, double[][] b)
    {
        arrayA = a;
        arrayB = b;
    }

    public Matrix(double[][] array) //Create matrix values
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



    public double multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b)
    {
        double[][] c = new double[a.length][b[0].length];

        System.out.println("Product of A and B is");
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++)
                {
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                    System.out.println(c[i][j] + " | ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

I know I have to pass an object/Matrix for the multiply method, but how would I do that?  There are other concerns in my code, but I want to focus on passing objects right now.

Comment: Your matrix class should contain only one array and your multiple method should have only one param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a deep look to your code:

1. Why do you have two double[][] inside the Matrix class? A Matrix is just one bidimensional array. You should delete the arrayB

   ```
   double[][] arrayA;
   ```

   ```
   double[][] arrayB;
   ```
2. What's the point of the private constructor? For you, it is useless right now.

   ```
   private Matrix(double[][] a, double[][] b)
   {
       arrayA = a;
       arrayB = b;
   }
   ```

3. In the public constructor, you are printing a Matrix, but you are not saving anywhere.

   ```
   public Matrix(double[][] array) //Create matrix values
   {
       Random rand = new Random();

       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
           for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
           {
               array[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
               System.out.print(array[i][j] + " | ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   ```

   ```
       arrayA = array;
   ```

   ```
   }
   ```

Anyway, I think it would be much better to make 2 constructors

```
    public Matrix(double[][] array) //you just pass an array created outside the class
    {
        arrayA = array;
    }

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) //Create matrix values
    {
        double[][] array = new double [rows][columns];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        arrayA = array;
    }
```

4. Why your multiply method have 2 parameters? As it is inside the class Matrix (that have a double[][]variable). You only need a parameter (I think it is better to your example to have a Matrix parameter instead of a double[][]parameter and return also a Matrix).
5. I don't like printing when you are creating or multiplying. It's much better to create a method to print the Matrix, and calling it when you want to print them.

So....the final code would be something like this:

**Main**
        public class MatrixMultiplication 
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
               Random rand = new Random();
               int rows = rand.nextInt(7) + 2;
               int columns = rand.nextInt(7) + 2;

```
           System.out.println("The matrix has " + rows + " randomized rows");
           System.out.println("The matrix has " + columns + " randomized column");

           System.out.println();

           System.out.println("The first matrix has the values: ");
           Matrix m1 = new Matrix(rows,columns);
           m1.print();
           System.out.println("---------------------------------");
           System.out.println("The second matrix has the values: ");
           Matrix m2 = new Matrix(columns, rows);

           m2.print();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Product of A and B is");
           Matrix productRegular = m1.multiply(m2);
           productRegular.print();
        }
    }
```

**Matrix Class**

```
    import java.util.Random;

    class Matrix 
    { 
        double[][] arrayA;

        public Matrix(double[][] array) //Create matrix values
        {
            arrayA=array;
        }

        public Matrix(int rows, int columns) //Create matrix values
        {
            double[][]array= new double[rows][columns];
            Random rand = new Random();

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                {
                    array[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                }
            }
            arrayA=array;
        }

        public Matrix multiply(Matrix m)
        {
            double[][]b=m.arrayA;
            double[][] c = new double[arrayA.length][b[0].length];

            for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < arrayA[0].length; k++)
                    {
                        c[i][j] += arrayA[i][k] * b[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }

            return new Matrix(c);
        }


        public void print(){
            for(int i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<arrayA[0].length;j++){
                    System.out.print(arrayA[i][j] + " | ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Correct, I was just focusing on the passing objects doubt

Comment: I think main is correct the probleme is in the définition of matrix class. See comment on question.

Comment: @popiandro - Thanks for the fast response! I want the method multiply to receive the Matrix class. But in this case, wouldn't the return value be double[][] and not Matrix? I have tried that code before but I always had an issue with incompatible types. Or do I have to change the whole code of my multiply method to return the appropriate value? Should I even be returning c in the multiply method?

Comment: @Kyshi I have edited the answer to explain more deeply what I saw wrong on your code. Take a look a it

Comment: @popiandro The reason why I had 2 double[][] was because I assumed I had to pass the 2 arrays(a and b) from the main class. I had completely forgotten that I had to store the values somewhere, and just assumed that the program automatically saved it. Anyway, thank you so much for all the help! It helped me understand the concepts better.